# How can I login with Cypress in a site that uses Google Auth?

Tags: google-oauth, cypress

I need to login with Cypress to a site that has Google Authenticator as a 2FV. I can enter mail & pass, but after this I need to complete the Authentication passcode shown in the app (Which changes constantly)

Is there any way to do this?

```
describe('empty spec', () => {
  it('passes', () => {
    cy.visit('website')
    cy.get('[data-selenium-id="email"]').click()
    cy.get('[name="email"]').type("mail")
    cy.get('[name="password"]').type("Pass")
    cy.get('[data-selenium-id="signInForm.signInButton"]').click()
    
  })
})
```

After that, the passcode is needed to continue:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9rKD.png)

I am expecting to skip this 2FV in anyway so that I can continue with my test using Cypress